# Apple Mach-O Linker Error: duplicate symbol _y

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

```
duplicate symbol _y in:
/Users/archanamehta/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GuideforCODGhosts-ftrljupdxywopwckemagyiliitss/Build/Intermediates/GuideforCODGhosts.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GuideforCODGhosts.build/Objects-normal/i386/SecondaryWeaponsViewController.o
/Users/archanamehta/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GuideforCODGhosts-ftrljupdxywopwckemagyiliitss/Build/Intermediates/GuideforCODGhosts.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GuideforCODGhosts.build/Objects-normal/i386/PrimaryWeaponsViewController.o
```

ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have an error in my application. Above is the error I am getting. I am not sure what to do. Please help.

Source code for .h file of PrimaryWeaponsViewController http://gyazo.com/1dd400959f043bddbc59ec8d0c4f6c60

Source code for .h file SecondaryWeaponsViewController http://gyazo.com/76b3d1fa2b766e904af41489e36cba60

Thanks

EDIT

I added the .m files in the comments section

Comment: Can we see the implementations? Looks like you have a function `y` in both?

Comment: It seems you have a global variable or method named `y` in both `PrimaryWeaponsViewController.m` and `SecondaryWeaponsViewController.m`.

Comment: .m file for Secondary http://gyazo.com/1ad5518054b79b633a86adb783fafe93

Comment: .m file for Primary http://gyazo.com/12a9e0ce7af8bb6a93ac3372486e5abe

Comment: Do you want to share `y` across both classes? Or do you want each class to have its own `y`? Or did you want each instance of each class to have its own `y`?

Comment: @user2852657 Please post how you fixed it.  It might help someone in the future.